# Почему не работает prerender.io? Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, koa.js

В качестве сервера использую Koa.js.

Что бы установить prerender.io использую модкль для Koa.js:
[koa-prerender](https://github.com/RisingStack/koa-prerender)
Делаю всё по инструкции:

var prerender = require('koa-prerender');

```
   var options = {
      prerenderToken: 'tk08Rp9xuhXXXrMHrOU7'   
   };

    app.use(prerender(options)) - подключаю перед роутом, который отдаёт index.html
```

Внутри index.html в  я добавляю

```
    <meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

Но всё равно сервер продолжает отдавать  index.html с JS, а не статический html.

Ни так

```
   https://site.ru/catalog/?_escaped_fragment_=
```

Ни так
        https://site.ru/catalog

В личном кабинете prerender.io пишут ghtleght;ltybt:

```
 " We haven't seen a request with your Prerender token yet."
```

Подскажите что нужно исправить в коде сервера? Я так понимаю с ним что то не так.

Comment: Ну Вам же пишут, что еще не получили от Вас `Prerender token`

Comment: @ Дмытрык, ну вот мне и не понятно почему они его не получили. Я ведь в middleware его указал, и запросы делал с ?_escaped_fragment_=. Почему тогда он им не отдается

Comment: сложно сказать, `koa-prerender` - не обновлялся 5 лет. Возможно в самом сервисе что-то изменилось. Попробуйте самостоятельно отправить запрос - посмотрите ответ.

Comment: @Дмытрык, разобрался) Там в модуле ошибка была) Спасибо за поддержку))